# Laravel Create Model for a pivot table

Tags: laravel, database-design, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have a `MenuItem` model which uses `menu_items` table with the following fields:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger( 'category_id')->nullable(false);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('price')->nullable(false);
            $table->boolean('available')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories');
```

Now, there are certain menu items which can have sides. These sides are also menu items and are defined by its category (`side` category).

For instance: I wanna have a `MenuItem` that belongs to a `MainDish` category. For this special category a menu item can have sides. These sides are also `MenuItem`. So I want to store the sides associated to a `MainDish`.

To do so, I've created a `menu_item_sides` migration:

```
Schema::create('menu_item_sides', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['main_item_id', 'side_item_id']);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('main_item_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('side_item_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('main_item_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('menu_items')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('side_item_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('menu_items')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

and its respective `MenuItemSide` model. As you can see, `menu_item_sides` has a composite key with 
`main_item_id', 'side_item_id'` and both keys point to the same PK in `menu_items`.

In this specific case, how do I declare the relationships between the `MenuItem` and `MenuItemSide` models?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the `belongsToMany` method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

```
  #Example for MenuItem model
public function menuItemSides()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\MenuItemSide', 'menu_item_sides', 'main_item_id', 'side_item_id');
}

#Example for MenuItemSide model
public function menuItems()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\MenuItem', 'menu_item_sides', 'side_item_id', 'main_item_id');
}
```

Or See: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many